# Delete rows from string array with just one value

Tags: matlab

I have a string array like this:

```
x={{'Na','Mg','Si'};{'V'};{'Na','Mg','Si','S'};{'Si'};{'Na','Mg','Al','P'}}
```

How can I delete all the rows which contain just one value, to obtain:

```
x={{'Na','Mg','Si'};{'Na','Mg','Si','S'};{'Na','Mg','Al','P'}}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a string array, can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: I am sorry. I hope I improved my question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a ["string array"](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html), you have a [cell array](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html?s_tid=doc_ta) containing cell arrays (in turn these contain [chars](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html?s_tid=doc_ta)).

```
x={{'Na','Mg','Si'};{'V'};{'Na','Mg','Si','S'};{'Si'};{'Na','Mg','Al','P'}}
```

You can get the number of elements in each sub-cell with

```
N = cellfun( @numel, x );
```

Then remove sub-cells with a single element using

```
x = x( N > 1 );
```

This could be done in one line

```
x = x( cellfun(@numel, x) > 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you really much. If I use this code, I get a result like this: 
1x3 cell
1x4 cell
1x4 cell
How do I get my Elements back into this array?

Comment: That result is in exactly the same format you provided in your example, which was a cell containing a `1x3 cell, 1x1 cell, 1x4 cell, 1x1 cell, 1x4 cell`, it's not clear what format you expect. My output is literally exactly the same as the expected output you wrote in your question